# Use Flask with Amazon DynamoDB without SQLite

Tags: python, flask, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a small web application using Flask and I have to use DynamoDB as backend for some hard requirements.

I went through the tutorial on Flask website without establishing sqlite connection. All data were pulled directly from DynamoDB and it seemed to work.

Since I am new to web development in general and Flask framework, do you see any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

No. SQLite is just one option for backend storage.  SQLite is mentioned in the tutorial only for its simplicity in getting something working fast and simply on a typical local developers environment. (No db to or service to install/configure etc.)